# Function definitions in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use parse-ez, and I don't understand why I'm getting the results I am. When I define what seems to me to be equivalent code in a function, I get different results:

```
(use 'protoflex.parse)
;
; Use an anonymous function, this returns [1 1]
(parse #(line-pos) "")
;
; Use an actual function, this returns what I think is a function pointer
(defn fooParse [] line-pos)
(parse fooParse "")
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke a function in Clojure, you do

```
(my-function)
```

If, on the other hand, you say

```
my-function
```

this is just a reference to the function. (“Reference” isn’t a technical term here, but I think that makes it clear what I mean.) In your second example, the “return value” of the function `fooParse` is this second form of the function—it’s `line-pos` instead of `(line-pos)`—and so the thing being returned by `fooParse` is a reference to the function `line-pos` instead of the *return value* of `line-pos`. I think what you want is

```
(defn fooParse
  []
  (line-pos))
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `line-pos` inside `fooParse`. Like this:

```
(defn fooParse [] (line-pos))
```

As you can see in the [docs](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters). The reader macro `#()` expands to:

```
#(...) => (fn [args] (...))
```